# NSMutableArray remains empty

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, closures, grand-central-dispatch

my knowledge on closures is still premature, Im having issues with adding objects to an NSMutableArray from inside a dispatch_async call which retrieves json data from the web, im attempting to add objects to an NSMutableArray which is initialized outside the function but it remains empty when i add objects inside the function, im sure there is another way around this ..... please help! And by the way if I remove the dispatch_async then everything works fine but i want to do the network call on another thread.

```
class Users:NSObject {

var  returnedUsersDetailsFromWeb = NSMutableArray()


func detailsOfUsersFromWeb(){

let url = NSURL(string: "http://Sheldons-MacBook-Pro.local/real/get_data.php")


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) { () -> Void in 


    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!){

    var error:NSError?
    let arr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSArray


    for var i = 0 ; i < (arr as NSArray).count ; i++ {

   self.returnedUsersDetailsFromWeb.addObject((arr as NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))


        }
    }

 }


println(self.returnedUsersDetailsFromWeb) // this is empty, if i remove the dispatch_async then this prints out everything
}
}
```

Comment: Dispatch needs to go inside the `NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)`

Comment: that works! but Isn't the NSDATA that takes potentially long to execute? and it should be wrapped in dispatch_async

Comment: You put the dispatch inside whatever takes a long time

Comment: @Caleb i thought it was the other way round, for example if I download an image from a url then i would wrap the NSData(contentsOfURL:) with dispatch_aysnc and not inside of it

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Wrap whatever code is using the data from the `contentsOfURL` in a `dispatch_get_main_queue()` and wrap the `contentsOfURL` in a `dispatch_get_global_queue`. You can always use breakpoints and check when the code is being executed just to make sure that you won't block the UI and you won't have any empty/nil values.

Comment: @Caleb I've tried putting dispatch_get_main_queue after NSData(contentsOfURL:) but no luck, what is going on? If you wouldn't mind sharing some code that would be great, :)